# how to validate user input password using if else statements

Tags: javascript, if-statement, passwords

Im having trouble declining the user access to the webpage based on what they put in for the password. Ive made it so, that if they put admin as the password, the page will display a div, but its not working. can someone help me find the problem.

```
<input id="passwordInput" type="password" value="">

<button id='signInButt'>SIGN IN</button>



<script>

var signInButt = document.getElementById('signInButt');

signInButt.addEventListener('click', function () {

        if (passwordInput == "admin") {

        signInPage.style.display = 'none';
        menuPage.style.display = 'block';

        dontHaveAccount1.innerHTML = usernameInput.value;

} else {
    alert("wrong password");
}




    });

</script>
```

Comment: that's not secure .and passwordInput  is a html element you have to get the value from it

Comment: Where do you define `passwordInput` , etc. ??

Answer (score 0):

It's insecure and you shouldn't do that way... just to correct your code:

```
var passwordInput = document.getElementById('passwordInput');
```

...

```
if (passwordInput.value === "admin") {
```